# Why is writing beyond array boundaries resulting in strange behavior?

Tags: c++

I wrote the code below:

```
int main()
{
    int currentSize = 0;
    int a;
    int b;
    int arrayA[currentSize] = {};
    int arrayB[currentSize] = {};

while(a > 0)
{
    cout << "Enter a: ";
    cin >> a;
    arrayA[currentSize] = a;
    b = a + 1;
    arrayB[currentSize] = b;
    currentSize++;
}
for(int i = 0; i < currentSize; i++)
{
    cout << arrayA[i] << setw(10) << arrayB[i] << endl;
}
}
```

I expected the output to be:

```
5     6
4     5
3     4
2     3
1     2
```

But when I ran the code, it came out as:

```
5     5
4     4
3     3
2     2
1     1
```

What have I done wrong here?

Comment: This is UB. `arrayA` and `arrayB` both have size 0. As long as the loop runs at least once, you are writing past the end of the arrays, and the compiler is free to make a program that does whatever it wants, including burn down your house, eat your cat, or output what it outputs in your case. Whether or not the loop runs at least one iteration is *also* UB, because `a` is uninitialized when it's first encountered.

Comment: This isn't C++. `int arrayA[currentSize]` requires a compile time constant for `currentSize` in C++

Comment: The code example could still be a bit shorter. I guess you would get the same behavior with only a single array. Please provide a [example].

Answer (score 3):

> What have I done wrong for this program?

You're using `cout`, `cin`,`endl` and `setw` which you haven't declared. If your intention was to use the standard iostreams, they are in the namespace `std` and declared in the headers `<iostream>` and `<iomanip>`. Solution: Include the headers, and use qualified names such as `std::cout`.

You have also declared array variables whose size are not compile time constant. This is not allowed in C++, and your program is ill-formed. Solution: You need to use a dynamic array. There is a standard container that implements a "resizable array" data structure: `std::vector`.

The array variables have a size of 0, which is also not allowed in C++, which is another reason for the program being ill-formed. Solution: This won't be a problem with `std::vector`.

If we are assuming that the program compiles due to use of language extensions, you are accessing the arrays outside of their bounds, which would be any index since they have the size 0, which results in the behaviour of the program being undefined. Solution: If you actually add elements into a vector and access the added elements, this won't be a problem.

In the first iteration, `a` has an indeterminate value, so the condition `while(a > 0)` reads that indeterminate value, and therefore the behaviour of the program is undefined. Solution: You could use a do-while loop instead.

Answer (score 2):

Your code exhibits undefined behavior. `arrayA` and `arrayB` both have size 0. As long as the loop runs at least once, you are writing past the end of the arrays, and the compiler is free to make a program that does whatever it wants, including burn down your house, eat your cat, or output what it outputs in your case. Whether or not the loop runs at least one iteration is also UB, because `a` is uninitialized when it's first encountered.

If you do not know the size of the arrays beforehand, you can use [`vector`s](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector): Declare with `std::vector<int> arrayA` and similiarly for `arrayB`, then use `arrayA.push_back(a)` and `arrayB.push_back(b)` in your loop.

You also need to initialize `a` before the loop's first iteration. If I correctly understand what you want to do, you can just do `int a = 1`.

Comment: When I say that the arrays have size 0, one should also keep @Caleth's good comment in mind: technically, they haven't been declared with a compile-time constant size at all, which they must. The compiler probably "helpfully" infers that `currentSize` can be deduced to be 0 at compile-time. One more wrong thing about the code.